# What is the best way to check if an object is a subclass and NOT the base class

Tags: python, python-3.x, object, subclass

let's consider the following code snippet:

```
class Vehicle:
    pass

class Car(Vehicle):
    pass

my_car = Car()

print(issubclass(type(my_car), Car))
print(issubclass(type(my_car), Vehicle))
```

Output:

```
True
True
```

Now if my task was to tell if my_car is of type Vehicle but not of type Car, how would I do that?

Is there a smart, short, elegant way for this?

Comment: Start with [inspect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html).

Comment: If `my_car` is a direct instance of `Vehicle` then `type(my_car) is Vehicle`. If it is an indirect instance of `Vehicle` then `isinstance(my_car, Vehicle) and type(my_car) is not Vehicle`.

Comment: Your title is the opposite of what you ask in the text.

Answer (score 2):

If `my_car` is a direct instance of `Vehicle` then `type(my_car) is Vehicle`.

If it is an indirect instance of `Vehicle` then `isinstance(my_car, Vehicle) and type(my_car) is not Vehicle`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `isinstance()`

```
isinstance(my_car, Vehicle) and not isinstance(my_car, Car)
```

Comment: but in my case both isinstance() would be True, so the full statement would always be False

Comment: That's because `my_car` is a `Car`. You said you want to find out if it's *not* a `Car`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code:

```
class Vehicle:
    pass

class Car(Vehicle):
    pass

my_car = Car()


if type(my_car) == Vehicle and type(my_car) != Car:
    print("my_car is Vehicle")
elif type(my_car) != Vehicle and type(my_car) == Car:
    print("my_car is Car")
```